# yumでインストールしたパッケージに含まれるファイルの一覧を表示するには?

Tags: linux, yum

python34 パッケージがインストールされているらしいのですが、どこにバイナリがあるのか分かりません。

`yum help` でコマンドの一覧を見てもそれらしいコマンドはなく、 `yum info python34 -v` でパッケージ情報を見ても、ファイル一覧までは出てきません。

どうすれば yumでインストールしたパッケージに含まれるファイルの一覧を出せるでしょうか。

Comment: `yum` はあくまで「rpm パッケージを管理するコマンド」であり、「yum パッケージ」という表現は正確ではありません。この点を踏まえて質問文を修正しました。

Answer (score 14, accepted):

repoquery コマンドはどうでしょうか？

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
repoquery --list python34
```

[yumでインストールされたファイル一覧を表示する方法 repoquery --list](http://kaworu.jpn.org/kaworu/2012-05-01-1.php)

Answer (score 9):

インストール済みのパッケージであれば、rpmコマンドも使えます:

```
rpm -ql python34
```